# MS-Word text to Excel table

Tags: excel, ms-word

I want to convert some MS-Word text to Excel table, but I don't know if there are some convenient ways to do it.

In MS-Word, it mainly contains choice questions, for example:

```
1. Which statement is wrong? (This description of question may contain multi-line)
A. ...
B. ...
C. ...
D. ...
```

And in excel, it need to be converted in such format:

```
column A                | column B | column C | column D | column E | column F
description of question | answer   | choice A | choice B | choice C | choice D
```

I am not familiar with MS-Word and Excel, can anybody give me some help?
Any help will be appreciated, or I will have to convert them by hand...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I find a way to make this task easier myself. I am using the MS-Word 2016, and here is what I do.

First, select the whole question:

```
1. Which statement is wrong? (This description of question may contain multi-line)
A. ...
B. ...
C. ...
D. ...
```

And click on `insert`, then `table`, then `convert text into table`, and Word will pop up a window, set the column to 5 (because one question has one description and four choice), and the row to 1. Click on `OK` and the format will become:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| description | choice A | choice B | choice C | choice D |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

Now, it has been converted into a table, and select the next question, convert it into a table.

Also, you can use the same way to combine the small tables into one big table, and copy and paste it to the Excel.

This is the best way I find so far, I hope I can help somebody here...